# Rx: Wait for several observables to complete

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have list of operations to complete and I want to return an observable which is notified when all the observables are completed (returning status of operations will be the best):

```
foreach (var id in service.FetchItems().ToEnumerable().ToArray())
{
    service.Delete(id); // <- returns IObservable<Unit>
}
// something.Wait();
```

`service.FetchItems()` returns `IObservable<string>`, `service.Delete(...)` returns `IObservable<Unit>`

Is the following approach correct?

```
service.FetchItems().ForEachAsync(id => service.Delete(id)).ToObservable().Wait();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid all awaiting and tasks and just stick with plain RX for this.

Try this approach:

```
var query =
    from id in service.FetchItems()
    from u in service.Delete(id)
    select id;

query
    .ToArray()
    .Subscribe(ids =>
    {
        /* all fetches and deletes done now */
    });
```

The `.ToArray()` operator in Rx takes an `IObservable<T>` that returns zero or more `T`'s and returns an `IObservable<T[]>` that returns a single array that contains zero or more `T`'s only when the source observable completes.

Comment: What if the observables are different types? IObservable<T1> and IObservable<T2>. An array will not work for me.

Comment: @NickGallimore - `FetchItems` and `Delete` are observables that return different types, yet the query works fine. Are you seeing a different issue?

Answer (score 0):

`ToEnumerable` blocks waiting for the next element in the sequence. You could do:

```
Task delAllTask = service.FetchItems()
    .SelectMany(service.Delete)
    .ToTask();
```

then you can block on the task or continue asynchronously e.g.

```
delAllTask.Wait();
delAllTask.ContinueWith(...);
```